# How to create a working OSGi bundle with optional package resolution?

Tags: java, osgi

I would like my bundle to be either configurable via System properties or via the OSGi Compendium Config Admin.

I am compiling my bundle against the `org.osgi:osgi.cmpn:6.0.0` bundle, which as [made clear in the OSGi Alliance blog](http://blog.osgi.org/2015/08/release-6-of-osgi-compendium-osgi.html) is meant to be used at compile-time only, with the framework providing the actual implementations at runtime.

My code obviously needs to use the ConfigAdmin package (to handle the case in which the ConfigAdmin Service is present)... which means that if the runtime does not export the ConfigAdmin package, my bundle will not resolve properly.

But I wanted this resolution to be optional... so I added this to the manifest:

```
org.osgi.service.cm;resolution:=optional;version="[1.5,2)"
```

Now, the bundle will resolve but will crash at runtime with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/service/cm/ManagedService` even if the user will not actually use ConfigAdmin for configuration. So this forces the user to install the config-admin bundle just to make my bundle work.

I guess the secret here is to not instantiate any classes that force the JVM to load a class that uses the `org.osgi.service.cm` package... but I can't see how I can achieve that without ugly hacks with reflection...

Does anyone know how I can check if the package is available at runtime, and if not, avoid the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` at runtime, making this package dependency truly optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PackageAdmin can be used to inspect package metadata of the system. It has been deprecated and you are expected to use the BundleWiring instead.
So, in your DS, you would have a dependency to the PackageAdmin/BundleWiring and check if the cm package is exported...

Comment: PackageAdmin is deprecated. Use BundleWiring instead.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it does answer what was asked, though now I found out I don't actually need to do that as ConfigAdmin is not necessary to configure a service in DS... I just didn't understand DS very well... oh well, thanks guys for taking the time to help.

Comment: @Renato Downvoting because this answer is simply wrong! WireAdmin is a completely different specification that is irrelevant here. BJ's answer is correct, you should accept it instead of this one.

Comment: @NeilBartlett the JavaDocs (of PackageAdmin) say to use the wiring package. As BJ corrected, it is the BundleWiring interface from the wiring package to use.

Comment: @NeilBartlett I have also edited the answer to reflect your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @erdal.karaca You haven't corrected the answer, it still says to use WireAdmin.

Comment: @NeilBartlett you're right, I was actually referring to the BundleWiring suggestion in the comments... but the other answer suggested that I should catch a NoClassDefFoundError, which I don't think is the right way to do it.

Comment: @Renato Catching the NoClassDefFoundError is exactly the right way to do it, and better still it doesn't create a dependency on OSGi APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The way to tell if the package is available at runtime is to attempt to load a class from it and be prepared for the NoClassDefFoundError. You could do this in a central place and then decide to avoid code paths which require the optional but absent package.

Comment: That's impossible if I use Declarative Services to export the service as the service itself must implement `ManagedService` to get config from ConfigAdmin. So I guess you're suggesting that I manually try to register the `ManagedService` and if that throws a `NoClassDefFoundError`, try to register the other? This is pretty ugly :(

Comment: Using optional packages is hard because you want the code to work when the optional package is missing. But if you are using DS, why on earth are you registering  ManagedService anyway? DS will handle interaction with Config Admin for your component.

Comment: sorry? You're saying I don't need to implement ManagedService in my service when using Declarative Services?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. See http://enroute.osgi.org/services/org.osgi.service.component.html#configuration and https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/cmpn/org/osgi/service/component/annotations/Component.html#configurationPid().

Comment: Ah, now I understand it... a DS service does not need to source config data from ConfigAdmin, it can use the "modified" method, which is purely within the DS specification, to get notifications of changes... and it can even get config through "Component Property Types" (section 112.8.2 of osgi-cmpn) in a type-safe way. This is much nicer than the old ConfigAdmin approach using a freaking Dictionary! Though I don't want to use DS annotations and osgi.enroute, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Renato Actually you don't need to write a "modified" method to get notification of changes. Normally your component will just be restarted when the configuration changes. If you need to optimise this – for example if the component is expensive to create and you have a quick way to internally reconfigure – then you can choose to provide a "modified" method. But it's absolutely not required (and rarely done in practice).

Comment: Is three a reason you don't want to use the DS annotations?

Comment: @PeterKriens I prefer to write all my wirings in one place. Just a personal choice, anyway everything annotations can do, I can do with XML (or my xml generator), right?

Comment: @NeilBartlett sure, but without a modified method, I don't get the new config values?? Or should I just use the activate method for that?

Comment: @Renato Without a modified method, your component will be destroyed and recreated. When it is recreated, the new config will be passed to the activate method. As I said: modified is only needed if you need to optimise, e.g. because your component is expensive to just destroy and recreate. It's very rarely necessary though.